# Writing into properties file using store and save method

Tags: java, properties

- What's the difference between writing into property file using store and save method?
- Does both do the same?

> save(OutputStream out, String comments)
>
> store(OutputStream out, String comments)

Comment: And what is is Rule #1?

Comment: Rule #1 http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: No Adrian - that is Rule #0 ... and it is a Rule for all programming, not just Java programming.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs on [java.util.Properties.save](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29):

> **Deprecated.** This method does not throw an IOException if an I/O error occurs while saving the property list. The preferred way to save a properties list is via the store(OutputStream out, String comments) method or the storeToXML(OutputStream os, String comment) method.
> Calls the store(OutputStream out, String comments) method and suppresses IOExceptions that were thrown.

So, `save` does the same thing, but swallows any exceptions. Unlike `store` it's `Deprecated`

Answer (score 2):

The `save` method is deprecated.
You should using `store` method instead.

More: [save](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and [store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)